# How to add JSR 303 validation to arguments of a method

Tags: java, spring, validation, hibernate-validator

I would like to use Hibernate Validator to validate arguments of my method.

I have tried to look-up examples and went through the following example
[JSR 303. Validate method parameter and throw exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829487/jsr-303-validate-method-parameter-and-throw-exception)

But the answer does not exactly solve my problem and also the links are expired in the answer.

Here is a sample code of what I have tried.

```
//removing imports to reduce the length of code. 

/**
 * Created by Nick on 15/06/2016.
 */

@Component
public class ValidationService {

    @Value("${namesAllowed}")
    private String validNames;

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    public boolean validateName(
            @NotEmpty
            @Pattern(regexp = ".*'.*'.*")
            @Email
            @Length(max = 10)
                    String name
    ) {

        Set<ConstraintViolation<String>> violations = validator.validate(name);

        for (ConstraintViolation<String> violation : violations) {
            String propertyPath = violation.getPropertyPath().toString();
            String message = violation.getMessage();
            System.out.println("invalid value for: '" + propertyPath + "': " + message);
        }
        List<String> namesAllowed= Arrays.asList(validNames.split(","));
        if (namesAllowed.contains(name.substring(name.indexOf(".") + 1))) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Method validation has been standardized as part of Bean Validation 1.1. You can learn more about it in the Hibernate Validator [reference guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-validating-executable-constraints).

With Spring you need to configure a [MethodValidationPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/MethodValidationPostProcessor.html) bean and annotate the constrained class with `@Validated`. Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21965098/773616) may be helpful to you.